# robotium test project builds in eclipse but not in ant

Tags: java, android, eclipse, ant, robotium

How do I configure ant to include class files from a separate project / separate directory structure?

I am trying to build an robotium android test project with ant. The test project references not the robotium jars but the robotium source code, which I have modified slightly (added a method and some logging). However when I try and run an ant debug right now, the compiler isn't seeing the robotium code.

How do I tell ant to include those robotium classes from the other directory? In eclipse it's working fine, as I have the robotium project in the build path. Looking for the equivalent in ant.

Thanks!!

```
-compile:
[javac] Compiling 3 source files to /Users/swolfe/Documents/git/android/automation-suite/sandbox/bin/classes
[javac] /Users/swolfe/Documents/git/android/automation-suite/sandbox/src/com/foobar/bookings/test/SearchTestHoneycomb.java:9: package com.jayway.android.robotium.solo does not exist
[javac] import com.jayway.android.robotium.solo.Solo;
[javac]                                        ^
[javac] /Users/swolfe/Documents/git/android/automation-suite/sandbox/src/com/foobar/bookings/test/SearchTestHoneycomb.java:15: cannot find symbol
[javac] symbol  : class Solo
[javac] location: class com.foobar.bookings.test.SearchTestHoneycomb
[javac]     private Solo solo;
[javac]             ^
[javac] /Users/swolfe/Documents/git/android/automation-suite/sandbox/src/com/foobar/bookings/test/SearchTestHoneycomb.java:23: cannot find symbol
[javac] symbol  : class Solo
[javac] location: class com.foobar.bookings.test.SearchTestHoneycomb
[javac]         solo = new Solo(getInstrumentation(), getActivity());
[javac]                    ^
[javac] 3 errors
```

Comment: Fyi for anybody who comes upon this in the future, what I did to work around was to add a copy step, where the needed classfiles were copied into the ant working directory and therefore available. something like this:

Comment: <property name="robotium-classes-rootdir" value="/Users/swolfe/Documents/workspace/robotium-solo/target/"/>
    
    <property name="build-classes-dir" value="./bin"/>
    
    <target name="pre-compile">
     <copy todir="${build-classes-dir}">
         <fileset dir="${robotium-classes-rootdir}"/>
     </copy>
    </target>

Answer (score 0):

You can jar modified Robotium classes, and put this file to sandbox/libs